# building web proxy with python

Tags: python-3.x, django

I'm building a website with django framework. I'm trying to add a web proxy tool in my website which will access the website entered through a proxy.

All methods I have researched are, for example if I use requests, urllib libraries it sends requests through proxy and gets me the response.text but I want to open a web page. another solution I have tried is `import subprocess as sp` and `sp.Popen(browser)` and it works in my system level because I need to mention chrome path everytime but I can't do it with end users. What is the instructions to make this system complete? thank you in advance...

Comment: Does it have to be served by an actual browser, or would crafting the request and parsing the response do the trick? An actual browser instance serving requests won't scale as well as simply making HTTP requests.

Comment: okay the details are, all the reference websites that has the feature which i'm following are opening a new tab instance in the same browser window. and the actual target link is hidden from the newly opened tab which instead displays the service provider's link itself. I read one more article about streaminghttpresponse, would it be the way I should proceed with? thank you.

reference website : https://hide.me/en/proxy
can crafting the request and parsing the response be done? i'm down to learn the entire setup and it's working.

Comment: Just redirect the request and responses like in https://github.com/inaz2/proxy2